# Hide table rows based on checkbox

Tags: html, css

I am trying to hide rows in my table based on whether or not their corresponding checkbox is clicked. I am not sure where to even start with the if statement and how to write it.

Here is the code for my table and checkbox

````
<label for="myCheck">Large:</label> 
<input type="checkbox" id="myCheck" onclick="myFunction()">

<p id="text" style="display:none">Checkbox is CHECKED!</p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  var checkBox = document.getElementById("myCheck");
  var text = document.getElementById("text");
  if (checkBox.checked == true){

    text.style.display = "block";
  } else {
     text.style.display = "none";
  }
}
</script>
<!--SCHOOL SIZE-->



<table id="myTable">
<table class="responsive-table-input-matrix">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">#</th>
      <th scope="col">Name</th>
      <th scope="col">Location</th>
      <th scope="col">Size</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    {% for college in college_data%}
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">{{college[0]}}</th>
      <td>{{college[1]}}</td>
      <td>{{college[2]}}</td>
      <td>{{college[3]}}</td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
  </tbody>
</table>```
````

Comment: Where is the `checkbox` and `myCheck` in your code.  i do not see anything.

Comment: Hey, Jackson. Welcome! We're happy to help. This question isn't as targeting as StackOverflow will expect. Can you narrow it down a bit - or provide an even more simple example? Maybe a jsFiddle or something?

Comment: I think that is what I made in line 2. I am very much a beginner at this so I could be way off. I am able to check whether or not the checkbox is checked, I just don't know how to make the row no longer visible.